# Period count function

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm new to the chrono library and I'm trying to use it to write a function that returns how many 5 min periods there are between two times. Please note: The 1min source and 5min result period could be different so the solution needs to be flexible (*e.g.* 5min source, 15min result period is one possible combination).

For example, I have the following general code:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

auto tp_now = system_clock::now();  //define 1st tp
auto tp_test = tp_now - 4min;       //define 2nd tp

duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 5*60>> five_mins;   //define a duration of 5mins
std::cout << "period_index = " << floor(five_mins(tp_test)).count() << std::endl;  //print out the 
                                                                                   //period 
                                                                                   //duration count
```

This code does not compile (I'm not sure why) but it hopes to display how many 5 min periods are within the 4min test period. Clearly, the 4min test period is a variable and could be different. Some examples of where the 4min variable is different with corresponding results are given below:

```
0-4 mins    result = 0
5-9 mins    result = 1
10-14 mins  result = 2
15-19 mins  result = 3
20-24 mins  result = 4
```

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`five_mins` should be a **type**, not a variable.

Also, `std::ratio<1, 5*60>` makes for 1 three-hundredths of a second, not 5 minutes.

```
using five_mins = duration<int64_t, std::ratio<5*60>>;
```

Furthermore, since there is potential truncation happening and the time is not in floating point, you cannot use the `five_mins` constructor. You HAVE to use `std::chrono::duration_cast<>`, like so:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using five_mins = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<5*60>>;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<five_mins>(std::chrono::seconds(700)).count() << std::endl;
}
```

You can see the formal details here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration, under constructor #4.

Finally, from your original question, you still need to convert your time point into a duration to get a fully working program:

```
std::cout << "period_index = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<five_mins>(tp_test-tp_now).count() << std::endl
```

Comment: I tried [this code](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwEEX3OcWAm1ZUutAKacxVSkhiHWgnpZm4Ec8eQ7sozvL/9x9j5/lsR0NDzgckOybnQdnXEihosScYIi/eTFoIJIbJIFU1fASUSxFpgCe@fT8hRXhAZCflJpHSpcUwBlJl2F57Pm31GqrbsW207lbPtgqJQaldV/3JoreBXKzuTVPXlwITlz8Kv1Ke3NiJb84/), do I do something wrong? It doesn't compile. Can you please correct it?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing: https://godbolt.org/z/hqbq35Pv6

Comment: @Arty I ammended the answer with additional explanation as to why you can't construct `five_mins` in this case.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for clarification, you code from answer [now works](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEETv@YoFL62o9KAV2phfKSGJdaHdlGbjRfz2GFpUBOc4s/N2zDTtzaCpT2mDZIZoHUhzmz15Jb4O@sCz06MSAolh1EhFCQ8BWTEg9XDFu@tGpAAXCGybZoU0jY2zZvQkc7E@drxb48WUp21dKdUunLXlI4OU/xGd0YHl55Mqfq6CM55sKM5VVZaHDCLOG98sR3ZoxTOlFw).

Comment: Thanks this also works after incorporating a hint from the previous answer: working code here: https://godbolt.org/z/vWEYzxv41

Answer (score 3):

is there some reason you don't want to write:

```
std::cout << (/*some duration*/ / minutes(5)) << std::end;
```

See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4)

For example, the value of `minutes(14)/minutes(5)` is `2`, and the value of `seconds(1000) / minutes(5)` is `3`

Comment: I tried this code (https://godbolt.org/z/oqj837d5j) and it didn't compile. The other issue is that if the source period is 5mins and the resulting period is 15mins it wouldn't work unless I'm missing something obvious. As I said I'm new to chrono.

Comment: Try `(tp_test - tp_now)/5min`.

Comment: @Andrew. You are confusing a `time_point` and a `duration`.   One is a measure of a span of time (5 minutes, say), while the other is a point in time (12:34 PM, say)

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks, that was the missing element I needed. Just need the tp reversing to get a positive result. Working code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/KPd8GxzWf
Thanks to all.